# Got the navigation bar height, but it's 20 pixels shorter?

Tags: java, android

**Situation:**

I'm trying to take a screenshot and save it to bitmap, and then crop out the status bar and navigation bar.

**Problem:**

Here's the code I'm using for getting the height of the navigation bar:

```
public int getNavigationBarHeight() {
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        return getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It returns 120 when in fact the navigation bar is 140 pixels.

I'm using the same code to get the status bar height, and it's getting the correct 60px.

Where went wrong?

Testing virtual device: Nexus 5x

Everything else in my code works, but the image came out with an extra 20 px of the navigation bar left on the top.

**Update:**

I tested on my Samsung Note 4, and again the returned height of the navigation bar is lower. It's returning 192 when the measured height is 224. And still the status bar is returning the correct height of 100.

**Update2:** 
Solved. Turns out I was looking at the action bar not the navigation bar. Should've read a book before I started working on this... Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind it's a rookie mistake.  Turns out I was looking at the action bar not the navigation bar. Should've read a book before I started working on this... Sorry for the confusion.

java android